# Remote debuging C++ project in Clion results in "GDBCommandException .. need to specify what serial device is attached .."

Tags: c++, clion

I've already set up a remote run configurations in CLion.
The remote server check is available, and the code has been synced to remote server.

However when I debug in clion, it always show error:

```
com.jetbrains.cidr.execution.debugger.backend.gdb.GDBDriver$GDBCommandException: To open a remote debug connection, you need to specify what
serial device is attached to the remote system
(e.g. /dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttya, COM1, etc.).
Debugger disconnected
```

How to specify the serial device?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

No perfect, but working solution (for me)
`Run->Edit Configurations->GDB:` change from `Bundled GDB` to `<path to gdb>`
If you using Linux, it should be something like `/usr/bin/gdb`.